# Error al enviar datos a MYSQL por AJAX Y PHP

Tags: php, jquery, sql, ajax, formularios

Estoy enviando los datos de un formulario, a través de ajax y php a mi base de datos:

Si pruebo con una variable solo o 2, si que funciona, si añado el resto, no funciona.

Mi código Ajax es el siguiente:

```
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'php/enviar_pedido.php',
    data: {'referencia': referencia, 
           'detalles': detallesCi,
           'tipo': tipoCi,
           'combi': combiCi,
           'familiaOD': familiaOD,
           'disenyoOD': disenyoODCi,
           'pasilloOD': pasilloODCi,
           'indiceOD': indiceODCi,
           'materialOD': materialODCi,
           'tratamientoOD': tratamientoODCi,
           'familiaOI': familiaOICi,
           'disenyoOI': disenyoOICi,
           'pasilloOI': pasilloOICi,
           'indiceOI': indiceOICi,
           'materialOI': materialOICi,
           'tratamientoOI': tratamientoOICi,
           'EjeOD': EjeODCi,
           'CylOD': CylODCi,
           'SphOD': SphODCi,
           'AddOD': AddODCi,
           'DnpOD': DnpODCi,
           'HOD': HODCi,
           'EjeOI': EjeOICi,
           'CylOI': CylOICi,
           'SphOI': SphOICi,
           'AddOI': AddOICi,
           'DnpOI': DnpOICi,
           'HOI': HOICi,
           'ColoracionOD': ColoracionODCi,
           'EspejadoOD': EspejadoODCi,
           'BaseEspecialOD': BaseEspecialODCi,
           'EspesorBordeOD': EspesorBordeODCi,
           'ColoracionOI': ColoracionOICi,
           'EspejadoOI': EspejadoOICi,
           'BaseEspecialOI': BaseEspecialOICi,
           'EspesorBordeOI': EspesorBordeOICi
            }
  })
  .done(function(listas_rep){
    alert('Pedido enviado con éxito');
  })
  .fail(function(){
    alert('Error 01')
  })
```

El archivo enviar_pedido.php es el siguiente:

(Los datos de conexión normales) + a través de $_POST[].. defino todas las variables:

```
$referencia = ($_POST['referencia']);
$detalles = ($_POST['detalles']);
$tipo = ($_POST['tipo']);
$combi = ($_POST['combi']); . . . .


mysqli_select_db($conexion, $dbname) or die ('No se encuentra la base de datos.');
mysqli_set_charset($conexion, 'utf8');

$sql = "INSERT INTO historial (referencia, detalles, tipo) VALUES (?,?,?)";

$resultado = mysqli_prepare($conexion, $sql);
$ok = mysqli_stmt_bnind_param($resultado, "sss", $referencia, $detalles, $tipo);
$ok = mysqli_stmt_execute($resultado);

if ($ok == false) {
    alert('Error en la consulta SQL');
    console_log( $resultado); 
} else {
    alert('Pedido enviado correctamente');
    mysqli_stmt_close($resultado);
    console_log($resultado); 
}
```

La cosa está en que si pruebo con solo un par de variables, me da OK y me lo inserta.

De esta forma, ni si quiera me manda el alert de error, pero tampoco envía a la base de datos.

¿Alguna idea de lo que puede estar pasando?
Muchas gracias de ante mano, y saludos.

FALLO:

```
{readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …}
abort
:
ƒ (a)
always
:
ƒ ()
catch
:
ƒ (a)
done
:
ƒ ()
fail
:
ƒ ()
getAllResponseHeaders
:
ƒ ()
getResponseHeader
:
ƒ (a)
overrideMimeType
:
ƒ (a)
pipe
:
ƒ ()
progress
:
ƒ ()
promise
:
ƒ (a)
readyState
:
4
responseText
:
"No se encuentra la base de datos."
setRequestHeader
:
ƒ (a,b)
state
:
ƒ ()
status
:
200
statusCode
:
ƒ (a)
statusText
:
"OK"
then
:
ƒ (b,d,e)
__proto__
:
Object
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82303/discussion-on-question-by-javier-avila-fernandez-error-al-enviar-datos-a-mysql-p).

Comment: @Dibort Olvida el error, si que encuentra la base de datos, había borrado una cosa, vuelve a pasar por el .fail :) edito de nuevo